Is it possible to fetch unique line item IDs for the same product in Woocommerce?
I have a very specific issue with Woocommerce and the YITH Multiple Shipping Addresses plugin. By default, Woocommerce doesn't support multiple shipping addresses, so all items in an order will go to the same delivery address and multiples of the same product use the same line item and just update item_quantity.
However, with multiple shipping addresses, the same item can be sent to different addresses. So, for example, a customer may have 2x 'box of chocolates', each going to a different address. I need to export this data into a spreadsheet for the customer to upload into their order management system. However, I'm having trouble finding something I can use to distinguish one instance of the same product from another.
Anything I can think to use provided by Woocommerce would be shared between two instances of the same product - get_product_id(), get_variation_id(), get_order_id() etc would all be the same for both 'box of chocolates' because by default, Woocommerce would simply update item_quantity rather than create a new line item for two instances of the same product.
How can I fetch or derive a unique line item ID or some other data point that can distinguish between two instances of the same product within an order that are each going to different delivery addresses?
I have tried get_product_id(), get_variation_id(), get_order_id(), I have dug into the plugin and found the YITH Multiple Shipping Addresses plugin stores address data in ywcmas_shipping_destination and ywcmas_shipping_contents metadata fields but even so, these don't seem to include some kind of ID to link to the product.

The plugin uses same product ID and creates additional metadata based on quantities this plugin is not what you need. To split you need from one checkout to create multiple orders based on the different addresses. But then you have to compare addresses too to avoid unneeded orders for same shipping address .. and merge into one order for that address.
